# OneDrive и родительская организация

Tags: onedrive

Купил аккаунт на Ebay и заметил, что у неё в родительских организациях указана реальная компания, которая занимается экскурсиями в Альпах.

**Возникли вопросы:** насколько безопасно пользоваться таким аккаунтом? Может ли родительская организация увидеть мои файлы, прочитать, удалить? Насколько много у неё полномочий?

> Хотел использовать этот аккаунт как внешнее хранилище для сайта, но
> теперь не уверен, стоит ли это делать. Ведь, если эта организация
> увидит мои левые файлы и удалит их, то может потеряться контент на
> сайте, что не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все логины смени ,и привязанные  номера телефонов если таковые имеются в системе.

Если все операции совершишь без проблем. То ни кто уже ничего не украдет.

Вопрос останется почему такой аккаунт возник, и не ворованный ли он через взлом.

Можешь найти сайт компании в интернете и обратиться к ним на прямую, как так получилось, и не имеют ли они претензий. Так ты обезопасишь себя от всех возможных проблем.

Comment: Ты, должно быть, слышал про акцию OneDrive, когда тебе предоставляли 5 тб памяти бессрочно. Вот такой аккаунт я и купил. А про идею связаться с владельцами, спасибо. Попробую.

Comment: Аккаунт удалили из MsOneDrive, товар удалили с Ebay. Вернуть через него средства невозможно. Остается надежда только на PayPal.

Comment: Взломаны значит был. Печальная история для тебя, но поучительная для многих.

Comment: Просто впервые покупаю на Ebay. Думал, что там защита будет нормальной, хотя бы как у AliExpress (сколько там заказывал, ни разу не киданули).